# What does returning a value really mean?

Tags: c

`return 0` is a convention that it will execute when there is no error and it will return `0`.
There is also a difference in writing return  0 inside `main()` func and outside `main()` func.

But what does it actually mean to return a value?

It might be copy of some question. But I have read all the answers and then only making a new thread.

Geeks for Geeks says:

> [image: pic credit geekforgeeks]

Comment: The `main` function is a special case.  Executing `return n;` from `main` is equivalent to executing `exit(n);`.  It causes the process to exit with status `n`.  `main` is normally called from `crt0`, and if `main` returns, that's how it's handled.

Comment: @TomKarzes inside main() what is returning a value after successful execution..

Comment: `main` is a function.  It is called as a function by `crt0`, which contains the process startup code.  If it returns, the calling code from `crt0` executes an `exit()` call, passing it the return value as the exit status.  There's nothing more to understand.  It's very simple.  This is not something that should be confusing you.

Comment: Please don't use the site you quoted as a source for learning the language. Almost everything I see on here from it is either completely wrong and written so badly that it will mislead the reader. For example in your quote: The first point makes it seem like `main` can return only `0` or `1`, when it can really return other integer values as well. The second point doesn't make any sense at all. What do classes and exceptions have to do with the topic at hand?? The third and fourth point (as well as the others) have grammar issues, wrongly using future/present tense instead of past tense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The August 4, 2022 working draft of the C standard, section 5.1.2.2.3 says:

> If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int, a return from the initial call
> to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value returned by the main
> function as its argument; reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0. If
> the return type is not compatible with int, the termination status returned to the host environment
> is unspecified.

The return value for any other function is user-defined.